# Сказуемое или определение?

Tags: члены-предложения, смысл

В разных источниках описание сказуемого и определения полностью размывается, якобы и то, и другое обозначает признак предмета или лица.
От этого и пошло и непонимание, как разграничить и понять что есть что?

Погода хорошая. - сказуемое

Хорошая погода. - определение

Прилагательное "хорошая" выражается по-разному в двух простых предложениях.
Вопрос тут не задашь, смысл у слов одинаковый, лишь порядок слов другой. Это ведь должно нести какую-то смысловую нагрузку? В чем смысл, помимо порядка слов?

Comment: Если глагола в предложении нет, то надо обратить внимание на порядок слов:

        определение обычно стоит перед подлежащим-существительным: У неё ***красное платье***;

        именная часть сказуемого обычно стоит после подлежащего-существительного: Её ***платье красное***.

Comment: Порядок слов необходимо учитывать только в этом случае? А если вот такое предложение: Кофе по-турецки. - Прилагательное после подлежащего.

Comment: Это не прилагательное, а наречие. Здесь нет составного именного сказуемого. Наречие ''по-турецки" здесь выступает в качестве несогласованного определения.

Comment: Хотел сказать определение, а не прилагательное, извиняюсь. Хотел спросить как раз почему здесь порядок слов не сыграл роли.

Comment: Наречия, зависящие от существительных, выступают как несогласованные определения.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Можете еще что-нибудь сказать по-другому вопросу? я ниже его написал, в комментарии к другому человеку.

Comment: Я правильно понял ваш вопрос: вас интересует разница между СИС (составное именное сказуемое) и определением?

Comment: Не совсем. На многих ресурсах сказуемое и определение имеет одно и тоже описание, а именно, что они оба могут быть признаками подлежащего. Допустим, что если в предложении есть признак(а не какое-то действие или состояние, которое точно можно отнести к сказуемому), то почему он относится к сказуемому, а не определению или наоборот? Ведь от сказуемого тоже можно задать вопрос "какой?", - так на ресурсах указывают. То есть здесь вполне резонный вопрос: в чем различие? Конечно, сказуемое более функциональное, но если забыть о других функциях и оставить только признак?

Comment: Mike, Людмила подробно объяснила. Читайте ее ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Именную часть сказуемого, выраженную полным прилагательным, причастием, порядковым числительным, действительно часто ошибочно разбирают как второстепенный член – определение. Чтобы не ошибиться, нужно обратить внимание на то, от какого слова ставится вопрос какой? к данному имени.
Если вопрос ставится от подлежащего или дополнения, то это определение.

Ср.: У неё было красное платье(какое платье?) ; красное – определение.

Если вопрос какой? ставится от глагола, то это именная часть сказуемого.

Ср.: Её платье (было какое?)было красное; красное – именная часть сказуемого.
Её платье(есть какое?) красное.

Сказуемое обязательно вносит значение предикативности, глагольности, бытия, семантика признака дополнительная, не менее важная для составного именного сказуемого.В нём сочетаются значения бытия и признака бытия. Он был там (важно бытие, присутствие). Он был больным (важно, что больной).

Если глагола в предложении нет, то обращаем внимание на порядок слов:
определение обычно стоит перед подлежащим-существительным.

У неё красное платье;

Именная часть сказуемого обычно стоит после подлежащего-существительного.

Ср.: Её платье красное.

Answer (score 2):

*Хотел комментарий написать, но уж очень длинно получилось. Пусть будет ответом.*

Да, порядок слов иногда значим и в русском языке.

Но тут у вас другое. *Погода [есть] хорошая* - по сути дело это составное именное сказуемое, "хорошая" в роли предиката, в которой обычно выступает прилагательное краткое (ср. *Погода [была] хороша*). Хорошо видно, если поставить в прошлое или будущее время. Но чтобы не морочить голову детям разговорами об отсутствующем глаголе-связке, приняли что сказуемое выражено прилагательным, это не отход от каких-то принципов, вопрос чисто терминологический, даже методологический.

А вот во втором случае как ни трактуй фразу как "хорошая [есть] погода", ну никак не получается, чтобы "хорошая" относилось к "есть", а не к "погоде".

А формально - да. Если не принимать во внимание порядок слов, то имеем неопределенность грамматического разбора *(её же называют "грамматической омонимией", но я разлюбил этот термин, у него есть другое значение)*. В любой модели грамматики естественного языка такие вещи неизбежны.

Comment: А что можете сказать по поводу значимости сказуемого и определения? Как я уже указал в вопросе, разные источники размывают эти понятия в единое, а точнее что они оба могут указывать на признак, за исключением, что сказуемое может быть еще состоянием или действием, в общем то, что говорится о подлежащем.